# FileError { kind: IOError(Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }), path: "Some(\"assets/images/tiles/air.png\")" }'

Tags: file, rust, directory

Tell me if I need to provide more info, I am rather new here. Here is the code:

```rust
let mut image_paths = vec![];

let mut images = vec![];

let mut image_path = "assets/images/tiles/";

for img in glob(format!("{}*.png",image_path).as_str()).unwrap() {
    match img {
        Ok(path) =>{ 
            image_paths.push(format!("{:?}",path.to_str()));
        },
        Err(e) => continue,
    }
}

for i in &image_paths {
    images.push(load_texture(i).await.unwrap());
}
```

But I get this error:

```rust
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: FileError { 
kind: IOError(Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }), 
path: "Some(\"assets/images/tiles/air.png\")" }', src/main.rs:71:43
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Which is really bizarre, because I can confirm that 'air.png' is in the 'tiles' folder, I have been able to load the image simply by doing load_texture(), but I don't understand why I cannot load it now.

Comment: What is the program working directory? Try printing the result of `std::env::current_dir()`.

Comment: /Users/pw/quirkscape, Which is weird. Because that is the home directory of my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Path::to_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.to_str) returns an `Option<&str>`. You're applying debug formatting (`{:?}`) on that, then adding the result to `image_paths`. I'm pretty sure your file path isn't supposed to start with `Some(`.

When you work with paths in Rust, you generally want to use `Path` or `PathBuf` unless you need to [`display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.display) the path. Check to see if `load_texture` could receive a `&Path` or a `PathBuf`. If not, then you need to `unwrap` the `Option` or deal with the `None` in whatever way is appropriate for your situation.

```
image_paths.push(path.to_str().unwrap());

// or if you need a `String` instead of a `&str`:
image_paths.push(path.to_str().unwrap().to_string());
```

Comment: I will check, but i am pretty sure it is imcompatable with load_texture()